# not able to run solr search example in hue 3.9

Tags: hadoop, solr, hadoop2, hue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ecCr.jpg)I have installed hue-3.9 and solr 5.5.3 in linux rhel. But I am not able to run solr search example in hue. 
When I clicked on install search in examples, it showing error like 'twitter_demo' is not available due to init failure.

Please help!

Full exception stack in hue:

**Error 500** {metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException},msg=SolrCore 'twitter_demo' is not available due to init failure: 
Could not load conf for core twitter_demo: Can't load schema /usr/local/hue/desktop/libs/indexer/src/data/collections/twitter_demo/conf/schema.xml: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "pint": Error loading class 'solr.IntField',trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'twitter_demo' is not available due to init failure: Could not load conf for core twitter_demo: Can't load schema /usr/local/hue/desktop/libs/indexer/src/data/collections/twitter_demo/conf/schema.xml: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml]

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: It's complaining about the Schema not being valid or able to load it from the configuration directory.

Comment: @MatsLindh , yes I found hue 3.9 is not compatible with solr 5.5.3. So I downgrade my Solr version to 4.10. now that error is resolved. But I am getting error : org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'source:': Encountered "" at line 1, column 7. Was expecting one of: ... "(" ... "*" ... ... ... ... ... ... "[" ... "{" ... ... ...

Comment: @MatsLindh , here is the link of snap-shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ecCr.jpg